# Takeown extremely slow on external HW RAID1 drive

Tags: raid-1, ownership

I moved a cheap external two drive RAID1 USB3 enclosure from my old PC to my new one. The file ownership was all wrong so I have been trying to take ownership of all the files. I was trying do do it through the windows GUI, but it would cause all sorts of crashes (windows explorer, edge) and generally very poor performance.

My latest attempt is using `takeown /r /d y /f M:` in an elevated cmd window. It starts off looking great, but soon slows way down, then grinds to a halt. If I kill the take ownership process and re-run it, it has the same behavior. Task Manager shows 100% disk active time, but little to no transfer. Sometimes I can't kill takeown and have to reboot. This drive has 100k files, so I need to find a better way.

I suspect that there's a conflict between the enclosure's hardware RAID1 and all the file changes which is grinding it to a halt. I wonder if removing one drive, making the changes, then re-inserting the drive to be re-built might work better. Should I wipe the drive I remove before re-installing it?